# Struts2 include tag

Tags: struts2

I've a requirement to include an html in jsp using struts2.

I used

```
<s:include value="objBarcodeCertificationTaskForm.strTrainingPage"></s:include>
```

the html path has to developed dynamically in action and set in the form bean

```
objBarcodeCertificationTaskForm.setStrTrainingPage(strTrainingPage);
```

But when i run the jsp i get an error saying "Requested source unavailable"

Is there a way to proceed using `<s:bean>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this and it's worked perfectly

```
<s:set name="embedded" value="%{'myjsp.jsp'}"/>
<s:include value="%{#embedded}">New Jsp Page</s:include>
```

I suggest you to observe the value whether you getting proper jsp name and you will get the above error message when it's not to find the resource. using following identify the value.

```
<s:property value="#embedded"/>
```

Comment: <s:include value="%{objBarcodeCertificationTaskForm.strTrainingPage}"></s:include> worked! Thanks

Comment: If it's really help's then accept the answer that will help community.